# Use td:hover, tbody:hover and rowspan together

Tags: html, css

in the first two rows of the table there are combined cells with the value "Männlich". The hover already works for the whole table but i want to add an other hover when the mouse is over each data. If i put a td:hover under the tbody:hover the datas aren't highlighted.

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* Dadurch bleibt die Überschrift an derselben Stelle stehen und man kann durch die Tabelle scrollen! */
}


/* Dazu muss Inhalt der Tabelle aber auch breit genug sein -> Zum Testen die Tabelle erweitern! */

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody:hover td[rowspan],
tr:hover td {
  /* Durch Aufteilung in zwei Bodys geht es, dass die zusammengefügten Zellen markiert werden! */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <caption>Kontakte</caption>
      <tr>
        <th>Geschlecht</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th colspan="2">Adresse</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Männlich</td>
        <td>Max</td>
        <td>Mustermann</td>
        <td>Musterstraße</td>
        <td>34</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hans</td>
        <td>Müller</td>
        <td>Schulstraße</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Weiblich</td>
        <td>Petra</td>
        <td>Mustermann</td>
        <td>Musterstraße</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `!important` in your css to the td:hover and tbody:hover see if that solves it?

Comment: This works for me: td:hover { background-color: rgb(98, 193, 224) !important; }

Comment: glad its solved your issue, sometimes css code gets overwritten by some other stuff so always try adding `!important` to let the code know, you want this to run as a priority, but use it wisely because it may have its negative effects if used randomly :)

Comment: Use `!important` with caution. If `!important` solves your problem during debugging, that usually indicates a specificity issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `!important` (which I would not recommend to use as it cannot easily be overwritten), just be more specific by using:

```
table tbody tr td:hover {
   ...
}
```

Also get rid of the duplicate `<tbody>` in your table if you don't need additional and different styling of the rows.

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* Dadurch bleibt die Überschrift an derselben Stelle stehen und man kann durch die Tabelle scrollen! */
}


table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody:hover td[rowspan],
tr:hover td {
  /* Durch Aufteilung in zwei Bodys geht es, dass die zusammengefügten Zellen markiert werden! */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

table tbody tr td:hover,
table tbody:hover tr td[rowspan]:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <caption>Kontakte</caption>
      <tr>
        <th>Geschlecht</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th colspan="2">Adresse</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Männlich</td>
        <td>Max</td>
        <td>Mustermann</td>
        <td>Musterstraße</td>
        <td>34</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hans</td>
        <td>Müller</td>
        <td>Schulstraße</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Weiblich</td>
        <td>Petra</td>
        <td>Mustermann</td>
        <td>Musterstraße</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks great. But what's wrong with my code? Something overrides the td:hover i think?

Comment: In your code there is no `td:hover`, only a hover pseudo element rule bound on the table row but applied to the table cell (`tr:hover td`). To make sure that the `:hover` rule bound to the table cell is applied, make sure to be specific (by using `table tbody tr td:hover`) to make sure that the hover bound to the row is not overwriting the one on the cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can try classes!

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* Dadurch bleibt die Überschrift an derselben Stelle stehen und man kann durch die Tabelle scrollen! */
}


/* Dazu muss Inhalt der Tabelle aber auch breit genug sein -> Zum Testen die Tabelle erweitern! */

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr:hover td {
  /* Durch Aufteilung in zwei Bodys geht es, dass die zusammengefügten Zellen markiert werden! */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

tbody:hover td.left-side {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <caption>Kontakte</caption>
      <tr>
        <th>Geschlecht</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th colspan="2">Adresse</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-side" rowspan="2">Männlich</td>
        <td>Max</td>
        <td>Mustermann</td>
        <td>Musterstraße</td>
        <td>34</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hans</td>
        <td>Müller</td>
        <td>Schulstraße</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-side">Weiblich</td>
        <td>Petra</td>
        <td>Mustermann</td>
        <td>Musterstraße</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Works too. But why do i have to use these classes?

Comment: I just lead the way, you can try any class names you want

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can come up with!

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* Dadurch bleibt die Überschrift an derselben Stelle stehen und man kann durch die Tabelle scrollen! */
}


/* Dazu muss Inhalt der Tabelle aber auch breit genug sein -> Zum Testen die Tabelle erweitern! */

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody:hover, tr:hover td {
  /* Durch Aufteilung in zwei Bodys geht es, dass die zusammengefügten Zellen markiert werden! */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

tr:hover td.hover {
  /* Durch Aufteilung in zwei Bodys geht es, dass die zusammengefügten Zellen markiert werden! */
  background-color: red;
}

tbody:hover {
  /* Durch Aufteilung in zwei Bodys geht es, dass die zusammengefügten Zellen markiert werden! */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <caption>Kontakte</caption>
      <tr>
        <th>Geschlecht</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th colspan="2">Adresse</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Männlich</td>
        <td class="hover">Max</td>
        <td class="hover">Mustermann</td>
        <td class="hover">Musterstraße</td>
        <td class="hover">34</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hover">Hans</td>
        <td class="hover">Müller</td>
        <td class="hover">Schulstraße</td>
        <td class="hover">2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Weiblich</td>
        <td class="hover">Petra</td>
        <td class="hover">Mustermann</td>
        <td class="hover">Musterstraße</td>
        <td class="hover">12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```